# access google cloud TPU in self-managed k8s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-tpu

Is it possible to access google cloud TPU resources in a self-managed k8s cluster(not GKE)? Is there a plugin of any sort to access the TPU resources from within the docker containers?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud TPU has been built into GKE and to do so a custom resource was defined with a separate control logic to handle that resource. This code is built into GKE, and if you wanted to self-manage a k8s cluster, you'd probably want to write this yourself. Personally, my recommendation would be to use TPUs through GKE as they're best supported that way.